# D latch circuit not working

Tags: digital-logic, analog, flipflop, latch, push-pull

I have made the attached circuit, to make a on/off switch for a power circuit. I have made the set and reset pins high. Also shorted the Q' and D.  After many trials, still stuck up with the output Q as 0. The problem that I think is that the input capacitance at CP is more, so help me re-calculate it.

[image]

Comment: Why are shorted the -R and -S pins ?

Comment: for making both high

Comment: Note that if mcu_bt_off_1 and mcu_bt_on are not used, you have -R and -S at mid bat+ voltage through the two resistors wired ...

Comment: Does GND get tied to the negative terminal of the battery somewhere else? What's making your flip-flop start in your expected condition? Are you even getting an edge on your clock pin?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have S- and R- connected together.  They have two different sources which have the possibility of fighting with each other.  If those lines are high, and you never need to reset it, no problem; if they fight with different values, that's a problem; if they're both low, the output may be undefined or it may not, but it won't respond to a clock pulse--again, problem.  They should be pulled up independently (and not pulled down), and not connected to each other.  If it still doesn't work, make sure they're both high before looking further.

The same goes for BAT+ and LED+VE.  You may have intended to do that, but now you have an net with two names, and a possible short.  You need a limiting resistor somewhere in the LED circuit; you could put that between BAT+ and LED+VE, and replace it with a jumper if you don't need it.

Further, when Q is high, Q1 may be driven into oversaturation, since there's nothing to limit the base current from the Q output.  This can also damage the components (although I assess permanent damage to be unlikely in this design).  Consider putting a 1-10K resistor between U10-5 and Q1-1.

If you still have trouble, consider including waveforms of the U10 pins at least.

Answer (score 0):

The Set and Reset inputs are active-low.  This is clearly indicated in the component symbol and in the front page of the datasheet.

In your circuit, both the Set and Reset inputs are enabled, not disabled, and the output stage is locked up.  Connect both inputs to BAT+ to disable them.

If you want to use either of these inputs, your schematic connections are not correct.  Please update your question with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: R18 is not populated, so ~R and ~S will both be pulled high.